# Login from new device (not mine)

Tags: icloud, security, apple-id, accounts

I have a new iPhone 5s (my first Apple device) and an iPad both of which I've had for three or four weeks now. This morning I received a notification that I had been signed in on another device, an iMac called "macen" (or something like that). I do not have an iMac. I don't recall the exact wording of the message.

I have changed my password this morning, and turned on two factor authentication, but how do I know that this other device no longer is connected to my Apple account? I checked in "devices" but only see my iPhone, iPad and my Windows laptop (where I have also signed into iCloud) .

What can I do to ensure my account isn't compromised?

---

Just found an email from Apple with the details:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Log into www.appleid.apple.com and from here you will see all the devices currently logged into your Apple ID, you can also delete devices that you don't recognise.

Here's what it looks like from my account.

[image]

Comment: Ok thank you. This only showed my 3 devices (same as on my phone). I guess I'm ok?

Comment: You should be fine especially if you've changed the password.